# Unable to import css in ReactJs application

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to convert an html template to a ReactJs application. Everything works fine with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/styles-merged.css">
```

in the `public\index.html` file but when I move the `style.min.css` file from the `public\css folder` to the `src\index.js`, then it does not work. I am sure that I am making a newbie mistake. What am I doing wrong?

**File structure**

```
public
   index.html
src
   index.js
   app.js 
   css
      style.min.css
   fonts
      glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
```

**Error:**

```
./src/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'css/style.min.css' in 'c:\projects\sample\src'
```

**public\index.html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/styles-merged.css">-->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
  </head>  
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**src\index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import 'css/style.min.css';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import './css/style.min.css'
```

You have to provide a relative path for the module to be imported that are in a relative directory (here inside `src`)

When you do

```
import 'css/style.min.css'
```

It'll try to look for that module in `node_modules` directory. It's because it's not there, you're getting

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'css/style.min.css' in 'c:\projects\sample\src'

Comment: I am now getting a "Module not found: Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot' in 'c:\projects\sample\src\css'. The css file refers to src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot). Should not this work based on the relative path of the css file to the font file?

Comment: You're getting this because the relative url to get that font is wrong in your css file. Try to figure out the relative path of that resource `./` will take resources from same directory `../` will go up a directory. `../../` will go up two directories. I'm understanding that this is because you move `style.min.css` down a directory. You might have to add a `../` at the beginning of that.